# WPF DataGrid auto after FontSize changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with some columns' width set to "auto". Now I'm changing the FontSize. When I make the FontSize larger, columns get wider, but when I make the FontSize smaller, the column width doesn't shrink according to the FontSize.

```
<DataGridTextColumn ....
                    Width="auto" 
                    ....
```

Is there a way to force the DataGrid to recalculate all "auto" and "*" values?

Comment: Where have you changed the code of FontSize?
Give a full code of your Data Grid.

Comment: I just set: dataGrid.FontSize = something;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reseting of column's width works:

```
 foreach (var dataGridColumn in dg.Columns)
            {
                dataGridColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(20);
                dataGridColumn.Width = new DataGridLength();
            }
```

Comment: In general, it does work, but is there a way to read out and restore the original values that were set for a column in XAML? My columns are not all *auto* and don't like the idea to have set column width twice, XAML and C#.

Comment: Yeah. You just need to save your grid width as a resource and restore it by code: this.TryFindResource("myGridWidth").
If it is unclear - post a new question and send me the hyperlync.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is set `ItemsSource` to `null`, and then re-assign it. Eg;

```
// This method works for AutoGenerateColumns = true
   Dgrd.FontSize = 8;
   Dgrd.ItemsSource = null;
   Dgrd.ItemsSource = ...;
```

And general method would be to store old width values of columns, and then using them to restore. Eg;

```
    Dictionary<DataGridColumn, double> columns = new Dictionary<DataGridColumn, double>();

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dgrd.FontSize = 20;

        columns.Clear();
        foreach (DataGridColumn col in Dgrd.Columns)
        {
            columns.Add(col, col.ActualWidth);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dgrd.FontSize = 8;            

        foreach (DataGridColumn col in Dgrd.Columns)
        {
            col.Width = columns[col];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried   /    var dgdSouce = dataGridDocument.ItemsSource;   /       dataGridDocument.ItemsSource = null;    /  dataGridDocument.ItemsSource = dgdSouce;/ but it does not work